# What does arithmetic mean for more than 2 numbers, say 3 numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, means, arithmetic-progressions

Arithmetic mean between 2 numbers are set of numbers such that all are in arithmetic progression.Therefore single arithmetic mean between two numbers a,b represents a number A such that a, A, b are in arithmetic progression and similarly n arithmetic mean between two numbers are set of n numbers such that they are in arithmetic progression

But this definition of arithmetic mean doesn’t apply to 3 or more than 3 numbers because if we apply the same definition it says arithmetic mean between 3 numbers(how is it possible one number between 3 numbers) represent a number such that all are in arithmetic progression!!!! How to apply this definition to 3 numbers

Comment: *"But this definition of arithmetic mean doesn’t apply to 3 or more than 3 numbers"* ... Correct. ... *"How to apply this definition to 3 numbers?"* Well, as you've observed, **this definition** (that is, the one you have described) doesn't apply to three numbers, so there's no way to answer your question as posed. That said, **this definition** (that is, the one you have described) is not the standard definition of the "arithmetic mean" of three (or more) numbers. Did you intend to ask for the standard definition of "arithmetic mean" and how **it** applies to three (or more) numbers?

Comment: @Blue you say **this definition ** is not The standards definition so is there any other definition also and if so then how can a same thing have two different definitions ?

Comment: We can define, as Pythagoras did, the "arithmetic mean" (AM) of two numbers as the middle number that completes an arithmetic progression. (The "geometric mean" and "harmonic mean" arise similarly.) That definition simply does not apply to more than two numbers. However, the "average" (the total of a list of values, divided by the number of values) applies to as many numbers as you like, and it *happens to agree with the AM* when only two numbers are involved. The mathematical community has accepted the average as the *generalization* of AM worthy of being called by the same name.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such concept as "n arithmetic mean", you are misinformed.

One can indeed compute $m$ intermediate values forming an arithmetic progression between two given numbers by the interpolation formula
$$\frac{ia+(m+1-i)b}{m+1}$$ where $i$ runs from $1$ to $m$. But there is no natural generalization to three numbers or more.

---

The arithmetic mean of $n$ numbers $a_k$ is the unique value$$\bar a=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n a_k.$$